# Is the decimal $0.1....1$ with $1$ in every $10^i$ an irrational or a rational number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

I came across this question: "Is the decimal $0.1....1$ with $1$ in every $10^i$ an irrational or a rational number?" and I am trying to figure it out, but I don't know where to start. The numbers I construct are $0.1 \cdots 1 \cdots 1$ with one in the first position (the only exception to the $10^i$th rule) , then the 10th, then the 100th, and so on... I am not sure this constitutes a "pattern", such that the number is considered rational but I am not sure I am right. Beginning with the definition if it is rational, it should be able to be written as $p \over q$. I also thought of multiplying many times with $10^i$ but I don't get anywhere with that idea. Any hints on how to approach this?

Comment: Hint:  decimals corresponding to rational numbers are eventually periodic.  That is, there may be a (finite) initial stub block, but after that they are periodic.

Comment: Your number clearly contains arbitrarily long sequences of consecutive zeros. See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4371098/decimal-expansion-which-consists-of-the-concatenation-of-the-powers-of-2-is-ir/4371298#4371298) to understand how that leads to irrationality.

Comment: Your $0.1....1$ is a little misleading for a quick reader and could be closer to $\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty 10^{-10^i} = 0.10000000010\ldots$

Comment: @lcmpereira: *Hint: Your number can be expressed as an infinite sum.* --- I just got back from an extremely hard aerobic workout, so I might not be thinking very clearly, but I don't see how to apply your hint.

Comment: @lcmpereira there exist irrational numbers who can be expressed as an infinite sum.  There also exist rational numbers who can be expressed as an infinite sum.  Your comment is unhelpful.

Comment: @JMoravitz: In fact, every real number can be expressed as an infinite sum (in which infinitely many terms are nonzero) because every real number has a nonterminating decimal expansion. I thought lcmpereira might have been thinking something like an infinite geometric series with rational first term and rational common ratio has a rational sum, and got confused over the hypothesis not applying (it would apply if all of the in-between sequences were the same).

Comment: To answer this question, you have to show that, if $n\in\mathbb{N},\ $ then $n\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} {10}^{ {-10}^i} \ $ is not an integer, which should be possible by elementary arguments.

Comment: It seems to me your number is a trascendental one (read about the first study of trascendentals by the french J. Liouville).

Comment: In fact it is a Liouville number and hence transcendental.